# Finding if a random number has occured before or not

Tags: algorithm, random

Let me be clear at start that this is a contrived example and not a real world problem.

If I have a problem of creating a random number between 0 to 10. I do this 11 times making sure that a previously occurred number is not drawn again, if I get a repeated number, 
I create another random number again to make sure it has not be seen earlier. So essentially I get a a sequence of unique numbers from 0 - 10 in a random order
e.g. 3 1 2 0 5 9 4 8 10 6 7  and so on

Now to come up with logic to make sure that the random numbers are unique and not one which we have drawn before, we could use many approaches

Use C++ `std::bitset` and set the bit corresponding to the index equal to value of each random no. and check it next time when a new random number is drawn.

Or

Use a `std::map<int,int>` to count the number of times or even simple C array with some sentinel values stored in that array to indicate if that number has occurred or not.

If I have to avoid these methods above and use some mathematical/logical/bitwise operation to find whether a random number has been draw before or not, is there a way?

Comment: Slight nitpick... If the state of the number is determined by previous states then it's not "random" :)

Comment: You can also populate a list with number `[1,10]`, shuffle it (fisher yates does it simply and efficiently) and return the next number in the list each iteration. When the list is exhausted - reshuffle.

Comment: dammit, that's my answer :)

Comment: Also: Is it always 10 numbers? If so - an `int` or `long` can be used as a bitset of all the numbers picked, and `pow(2,candidate) & set` will be zero if and only if `candidate` was not chosen before. Similar to the `bitset` approach.

Comment: @Amit - No its not always 10 numbers. It can be pretty large value, so that was one of the reason to avoid a separate array which can be of large size. David - Point noted. Not exactly random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have to avoid these methods above and use some
>   mathematical/logical/bitwise operation to find whether a random number
>   has been draw before or not, is there a way?

Subject to your contrived constraints yes, you can imitate a small bitset using bitwise operations:

You can choose different integer types on the right according to what size you need.

```
bitset code                    bitwise code

std::bitset<32> x;             unsigned long x = 0;
if (x[i]) { ... }              if (x & (1UL << i)) { ... }
// assuming v is 0 or 1
x[i] = v;                      x = (x & ~(1UL << i)) | ((unsigned long)v << i);
x[i] = true;                   x |= (1UL << i);
x[i] = false;                  x &= ~(1UL << i);
```

For a larger set (beyond the size in bits of `unsigned long long`), you will need an array of your chosen integer type. Divide the index by the width of each value to know what index to look up in the array, and use the modulus for the bit shifts. This is basically what `bitset` does.

I'm assuming that the various answers that tell you how best to shuffle 10 numbers are missing the point entirely: that your contrived constraints are there because you do not in fact want or need to know how best to shuffle 10 numbers :-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to do it the way you suggest. Consider what happens when you have already selected 10 of the 11 items; your random number generator will cycle until it finds the missing number, which might be never, depending on your random number generator.

A better solution is to create a list of numbers 0 to 10 in order, then shuffle the list into a random order. The normal algorithm for doing this is due to Knuth, Fisher and Yates: starting at the first element, swap each element with an element at a location greater than the current element in the array.

```
function shuffle(a, n)
    for i from n-1 to 1 step -1
        j = randint(i)
        swap(a[i], a[j])
```

We assume an array with indices 0 to n-1, and a randint function that sets j to the range 0 <= j <= i.

Comment: The `shuffle()` function is exactly fisher-yates shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and add all possible values to it. Then pick one out of the array and remove it. Next time, pick again until the array is empty.

Comment: "pick one value" is problematic. Shuffling the list and iterating is the way to go. However, it does not answer the question: `use some mathematical/logical/bitwise operation to find whether a random number has been draw before or not, is there a way?`

Comment: Why is that problematic? You can shuffle it or pick a random index. Neither is any better or worse if you talking about good or bad randomness.

Comment: removing an element from an array is O(N) time, so your algorithm is O(N^2) if you run it until the array is empty. If you shuffle a stack once and iteratively pop elements until it's empty, it's O(N) time total.

Comment: So it's slow, not "problematic" ;)

Comment: Not only you have to reorder the array, but I am looking to avoid extra space which would be O(N)

Comment: @goldenmean: it is not possible to store `N` arbitrary true/false values in less space than `O(N)`, so if you are using a good RNG that you don't control, it's not possible to avoid the extra space. You could perhaps find or design a random number generator with range N and period N, so that you don't need to track what has already been chosen because your RNG doesn't produce duplicates. How easy that is depends how good an RNG you need: it's easy to do a rubbish RNG with the required property since any number coprime to `N` has order `N` in the additive group modulo `N`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a **mathematical** way to do it, but it is a bit expansive.

have an array: `primes[]` where `primes[i] = the i'th prime number`. So its beginning will be `[2,3,5,7,11,...]`.

Also store a number `mult` Now, once you draw a number (let it be `i`) you check if `mult % primes[i] == 0`, if it is - the number was drawn before, if it wasn't - then the number was not. chose it and do `mult = mult * primes[i]`.

However, it is expansive because it might require a lot of space for large ranges (the possible values of `mult` increases exponentially

(This is a nice mathematical approach, because we actually look at a set of primes `p_i`, the array of primes is only the implementation to the abstract set of primes).

---

A **bit manipulation** alternative for small values is using an `int` or `long` as a bitset.

With this approach, to check a candidate `i` is not in the `set` you only need to check:

```
if (pow(2,i) & set == 0) // not in the set
else //already in the set
```

To enter an element `i` to the set:

```
set = set | pow(2,i)
```

---

A better approach will be to populate a `list` with  all the numbers, shuffle it with [**fisher-yates shuffle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and iterate it for generating new random numbers.

Comment: Primes[] approach is nice but still extra storage. Looking at answers , i see that best i can do is implement the bitset functionality using a unsigned long int []. Although some usage would be needed in that approach too, but it would be N/(sizeof(unsigned long int))

Comment: @goldenmean: There is another issue with this approach, note that when your bitset is almost full, it will take `O(N)` (on average) to find an available number. Using fisher-yates you get `O(1)` amortized time complexity per element.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable too map the drawn numbers. The i'th bit of that variable will be 1 if the number was drawn before:

```
int mapNumbers = 0;

int generateRand() {        
    if (mapNumbers & ((1 << 11) - 1) == ((1 << 11) - 1)) return; // return if all numbers have been generated
    int x;  
    do {
        x = newVal();
    } while (!x & mapNumbers);
    mapNumbers |= (1 << x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a use of uninitialized variable - x in the if check.What is x meant to be initially.

Comment: my bad, instead of x should have been mapNumbers. I edited that.